# Using First() with OrderBy and DynamicQuery in One-To-Many related tables

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by, one-to-many, dynamicquery

> Note:  I realize this question is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604729/using-0-or-first-with-linq-orderby), however that question was asked in the context of Genom-e and remains unanswered.  My question is in the context of LINQ DynamicQuery.

I'm using the `String` extension method overload for `OrderBy` provided by `System.Linq.Dynamic`.  Passing a String Literal to `OrderBy` works great.  I can sort on primary entity fields ie: `person.OrderBy("LastName")` and I can sort on children entity fields as long as there is a one-to-one relationship between the parent and child ie: `person.OrderBy("Mother.LastName")`.

However, I am unable to sort on a child's field if there is a one-to-many relationship with the parent and child ie: `person.OrderBy("Children.LastName")`.  This throws an error: `No property or field 'Children' exists in type 'Person'`.

Obviously this fails because the interpreter doesn't know *which* child's `LastName` I'm trying to use in the sort operation.  I can solve this problem easily by creating an expression like this `(Function(p As Person) p.Children.First.LastName)`.

But how can I get similar `First` behavior when using the string literal extension of `OrderBy`?  Ultimately I want to be able to do something like this: `person.OrderBy("it.Lastname desc, Children.First().FirstName asc")`

**Edit:**  I'm using the Repository pattern and this is what my `Find` function looks like:

```
Public Function Find(ByVal predicate As Expression(Of Func(Of TEntity, Boolean)), ByVal orderBy As String, ByVal skip As Integer, ByVal take As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of TEntity) Implements ILinqSqlRepository(Of TEntity, TContext).Find

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy) Then
            Return Find(predicate, skip, take)
        Else
            Dim qry = Context.GetTable(Of TEntity)().Where(predicate).OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(skip).Take(take)
            Return qry.ToList()
        End If

    End Function
```

**Edit:** This is the relationship between `Person` and `Child` tables:

```
Person Table
  PersonId (pk)
  MotherId (fk to Mother Table)
  LastName
  FirstName

Child Table
  ChildId (pk)
  PersonId (fk to Person Table)
  LastName
  FirstName

Mother Table
  MotherId (pk)
  LastName
  FirstName
```

Each `Person` may have 0 or more `Children`.  You can see there can be 0 or 1 `Mother` rows for each `Person`.

Obviously these are not the exact table names I'm using in my real project but you can see how relationships between `Person` and `Mother`, and with `Person` and `Child` are different.

**Selector**
I've tried overloading `Find()` to accept a `Selector` which selects `p = Person` and `child = First().Child` but the return type changes to Anonymous, instead of the Generic type.  Is there some way to use the `Selector` in the `OrderBy` process but still return a `IEnumerable(of TEntity)`?

Comment: What's the relationship between the person and children tables?

Comment: Edit: formatting was messed up.

There are 0-n Child rows for each Person row.  For example:  Table Person: PersonId (pk), Table Child: ChildId (pk), PersonId  (fk to Person table), LastName

Answer (score 1):

You could do (C#, sorry...):

```
people.Select(p => Person = p, Child = p.Children.First())
      .OrderBy("Child.LastName")
      .Select(p => p.Person);
```

BTW, without `"it.` you're using `System.Linq.Dynamic`, and with `"it.` you're using ESQL. Either one is OK, but *you should not use both!*

Comment: Craig, thank you for your comment.  I manually typed the code snippets and accidentally added the `it.`.  I'm not using it in the real code.  I've updated the question to show how I'm using the Repository pattern, passing in condition predicates.  I'm not sure how to add a selector in the `Find` function and still keep the function generic.